# Mongoid why should I use update_all instead of simply looping over collection and saving

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using Mongoid in one of my rails project. I have a very big collection for which I would like to update a specific field of every document. 
I feel that I should use the `update_all` method from Mongoid :

```
Collection.all.update_all(field: new_value)
```

However in what way is it better than doing :

```
Collection.all.each do |document|
  document.field = new_value
  document.save
end
```

Can you please explain what is doing the `update_all` method that makes it more performant than a simple loop saving every single doc. Do you know any other way/method that could make my code more performant.

____EDIT___

I also checked a gem like that enables to run code in parallel :
https://github.com/grosser/parallel
Another option for my code would then be :

```
  licenses = License.all
    Parallel.each(licenses, in_processes: 6, progress: 'setting scope_type individual for license_offers') do |license|
      license.license_offer.scope_type = :individual
      license.save!
    end
```

How can I determine what is the most performant option ?

Answer (score 2):

with update_all no instantiation, callback or validations are made. It just run one single query.
But in case of updating in loop. If there are 1000 records to update it will execute 1000 queries and validations and call backs will also run which will show the process and consume more memory

Comment: thanks @Danial, Do you know if it would be possible to combine the update_all one query with parallel processing ?